# ColdFusion 10 server won't start

Tags: apache, debugging, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have ColdFusion 10 (Developer) installed over Apache 2.2.24 on a Windows 7 machine. Everything was working fine except for the line debugger (via Eclipse). While hunting around for a solution I changed the debugging port to 80 (from 8000). I tried to restart the server and now nothing works. I either need to find a way to fix the problem using the command prompt or re-install ColdFusion 10. This is, therefore, a two part question.

1. Can I fix the current installation? Here is the error I get when I try to start the server from DOS:

   c:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin>coldfusion start
   ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
   ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:741]
   FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
2. Can I create a .car file of my settings from DOS before I re-install ColdFusion 10?

One piece of information that may be relevant is that I tried to move CFIDE from `ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/` to `inetpub/wwwroot/` (because that is where I have the rest of my files). Before the move both the server and the debugger worked. After I moved the directory, the server still worked but the debugger stopped working. I changed the path to CFIDE in `C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf` and `mod_jk.conf`. I know, I should have moved CFIDE back to its original location then left well enough alone, but that's water under the bridge.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debugger settings are in the `jvm.config` file, located in the `[instance]/bin` dir, eg for me it is `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin\jvm.config`.

You'll see this sort of thing:

```
-DDEBUGGER_SERVER_PORT=portNumber
```

And currently it'll probably say `80`. Obviously(?) one should *not* try to make the debugger listen on the same port as the web server ;-).

You oughtn't've moved your CFIDE dir: it was in the correct place to start with. However if you want to browse to it, just make an alias to it in your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

I also recommend only changing one thing at a time when messing with stuff. IE: get the debugger working, *then* try to move CF's internal files to different locations, etc. Trying to do both at once is not helping your situation, as you probably now have two things preventing CF from starting, and even if you fix one, you won't know as the other will still be stuffing things up.

As for getting the debugger working... raise a different question for that, or try to make sense of the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0d389-7fff.html).

Comment: Thanks Adam! Changing the server port back to 8000 in jvm.config fixed the problem of the server not starting. I'll leave CFIDE in it's original location. You're right about changing only one thing at a time. I know that's what I should do but I get impatient and make this mistake too often. Now I'm off to fix the line debugger, one change at a time.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted. If you end up needing to ask a question about the debugger, raise it here and then hit me up on Twitter... I won't be able to help so much, but I know someone who probably can. @daccfml.

Comment: I fixed the line debugger by removing a customtag path that pointed to the root directory for the whole site. I saw another thread somewhere about customtag paths to directories with many files slowing down the debugger.

Comment: In CF11 and CF2016, the debugger server port is also specified in the jvm.config, but the line where I found it is a little different than this answer. Look for something like this: `java.args=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=port_number`